# Java: Using a scanner.nextLine().equals("example")) needing repeated input

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am using a Scanner to detect input from the user, the idea is that the user can type "help" or "test" into the terminal at any time to display an out put.

So far my code works because I have to hit enter twice to see an output when I type. This what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game
{
    static Scanner command = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GAME:
        while (var.running == true)
        {
            check.controls();
            command.nextLine();
        }
    }
}

public class check extends Game
{
    public static void controls()
    {
        if (command.next().equals("help"))
        {
            System.out.println("This is the help Menu");
        }

        else if (command.next().equals("test"))
        {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that when typing "help" and then immediately typing "test" noting will register the first time.

Comment: very bad use of inheritance

Comment: I am very new to programming so I am open to any helpful criticism, how could I improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the class `check`, you are scanning twice to see if the entered data is equal to `test`. So let's say you entered `test`, the first condition will read `test` and will evaluate it with the string `help`, so condition false, then it will do the same for the second condition where it asks again for another input, if you enter `test` this time, it will evaluate it with `test` and the condition is true.

Here's  how you can fix it:

```
class check extends Game
{
    public static void controls()
    {
        String commands = command.next();
        if (commands.equals("help"))
        {
            System.out.println("This is the help Menu");
        }

        else if (commands.equals("test"))
        {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, you don't need to scan `next()` twice, do it one time and evaluate it using the `if else if` statement

Comment: Thank you very much :) I am a first year student so I am still on the basics. This worked perfectly!